# jQuery UI sortable is not sorting when ul is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Take the example I have setup at http://jsfiddle.net/vEF6y/

Click on the 'add item' button 3 times to add 3 boxes, then try sorting them.

This is almost impossible to do when there are no items initially in the `<ul>`

Does anyone have any solutions to fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/znGNk/3/

but I don't consider that as a clean solution. Maybe you shouldn't initialize sortable if there are no items.